# How to wait until I get a specific response in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm doing load testing using JMeter for my gaming application.

First I log in my application by HTTP request and then enter into the game(it is a WebSocket connection).

I successfully hit Websocket and able to send the request and receive a response.
Iam using  WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch.WebSocket request-response Sampler captures one response at a time.

But in my application for a single request **five** JSON response is returned by the server. I need to capture those five responses. so I used WebSocket read sampler.

If I hit that WebSocket by increasing thread count most of the test cases are failed because of timer issue.

Jmeter sends the next request without waiting for previous reponse.

In my application, if one game ends, then the response is sent by the server. After receiving that only next game request must hit.

But the next game request hit the server before the current game ends. can please help me to sort this issue????

Comment: Any answer regarding this question????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `WebSocket read sampler` under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) and specify the condition for exiting the while loop (it might be something coming from the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor))

> Jmeter sends the next request without waiting for previous reponse.

this statement is not true, each thread (virtual user) waits for the current sampler to finish before starting the next sampler

Comment: I had used the loop controller before read sampler. Now I changed the script.I'm using WebSocket text frame filter before that read sampler to get the exact response from the server. I will check with while loop controller as u suggested. Thank you so much!